# Why is the AWS CLI failing with the error "Unknown Options" when I try to reboot RDS with failover?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I am running the following command using aws cli but it is complaining about unknown options. The exact error is: "Unknown options: true"

```
aws rds reboot-db-instance --db-instance-identifier 'myinstance' --force-failover true --profile myaccount
```

This instance is set for multi-AZ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs in the AWS CLI when unknown options are found.  It can return multiple "unknown" strings joined by a comma, as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/926). In your case, the cli is trying to parse `true` as an option and failed because `--force-failover` does not require a value.

From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/reboot-db-instance.html):

```
  reboot-db-instance
--db-instance-identifier <value>
[--force-failover | --no-force-failover]
```

The brackets indicate that you can specify `--force-failover` *or* `--no-force-failover`, and also that no value is required for either since it does not specify `<value>`.

Just remove "true" and you should be set.